# How to prevent Gmail from breaking layouts by creating map link from address?

Tags: gmail, html

Gmail is breaking emails layouts with maps link. It is adding randomly "" into HTML's templates. Like this:
[image: example]
Please, if if anyone knows something to avoid this, tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Use tables and supported [CSS properties and media queries](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css).